# How can I import all my Windows files into Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, files

My Windows 10 has crashed, and now I would like to go with Ubuntu 14.04. I have my working files in other drives. How can I import  my files from Windows to Ubuntu without loosing them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do, is inserting a live-medium, DVD or USB-Drive with Ubuntu. Then I attach my external drive to the computer and open a file-browser. After a click on the HDD with Windows you can just copy every file to that external medium.

After the installation is completed you can recopy the files to your internal HDD.

Be aware to copy all files you need, typically folder like musik, documents, own files, desktop,etc.

Linux don't care if there is a working OS in that HDD. But if your HDD failed (Hardware-Defect) Ubuntu will not be able to mount it. Unfortunately it is not a magical unicorn.

Comment: Now that i cannot go  through my files.As my Pc is just showing the manufacturer Logo and then it will stop there.I cannot Login into my Profile.Any way i have to install other OS(UBUNTU).After installation whatever files were there in other Drives, will those files be safe???

Comment: If your computer only shows the manufacturer logo, I would say, your windows did not crash, in fact I believe your windows still works, but your mainboard or another part has a defect. Try disconnecting your harddrive, or remove it if it is a laptop, if it is a desktop, also remove other peripheries like DVD-drive. And push the power button. If its going behind the logo and says e.g. **no bootable drive** or something similar, it has to be something you detached. If it's not going behind that logo, it is your mainboard, your CPU or something else.

Comment: Initially my windows is working fine.what happened is i created a partition to install ubuntu in that.While installation with ubuntu we should create 3 partitions (SWAP,root,home),after that while installation got a message NO SPACE AND INSTALLER CRASHED. and I thought to do installation again.When i switched on my Pc Logo came and then i cannot see anything.......

Comment: Please, always give detailed information! That **NO SPACE** is really important. Go into the BIOS and change the settings to first boot your DVD or USB-drive, then your computer is not booting from the HDD and you can reinstall Ubuntu and resize all your partitions.